# Why preg matc is not working?

Tags: php

I need help on this. Can not  get `preg_match` to work!

I have form with method `POST` and input is `name="name"`

then i call `$name = $_POST["name"];`

So this is my code.

`$dosome = strip_tags( $_REQUEST["dosome"] );`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="dosome" value="example" />
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search for TV" />
<input type="submit" value="Meklēt" />
</form>


`if ( $dosome == "example" ) {
  if ( preg_match("/@^(.*?)[.][Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+@/", $name, $m ) ) {
    $search = str_replace( '.', ' ', $m[1] );
    echo $search;
  }
}`
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: So whats not working? Show input and expected output.

Comment: Try changing `name= "uname"` or something different than `name`

Comment: @surjit why would `name="name"` not work?

Comment: Have tried [looking at your pattern to see what types of things it will match](https://regex101.com/r/Exsb4v/1)?  Here is one example: `Hello.s1E0@`.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `@` or `/` delimiter and not both.

```
$str = 'dds.s12e0';
var_dump(preg_match('@^(.*?)[.][Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+@', $str)); // works, output: 1
var_dump(preg_match('/@^(.*?)[.][Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+@/', $str)); // won't work, output: 0
```

If you intend to match the `@` symbol then your regex should be:

```
/^@(.*?)[.][Ss][0-9]+[Ee][0-9]+@/
```